# How do I get JavaScript to recognize a clicked element by class name?

Tags: javascript, meteor, foreach, onclick

I have an app that displays various images, each with a unique `_id`, but they all share the class name: `uploadedImage`. When an image is right clicked, I would like for the event to add the images unqiue `_id` to the `clickedImage` array.

Find below, the above description in code:

```
 'contextmenu .uploadedImage': function(){

 var clickedImage = [];

 $('.uploadedImage: onclick').forEach(function(index ){

     clickedImage.push(this._id);
     console.log(,...clickedImage);
    });
```

When I run this code, I get the below error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .uploadedImage: onclick
```

Find below my image class architecture:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 uploadedImage">
<div class="well">
</div>              
</div>
```

So, how do I get JavaScript to correctly recognize a clicked (right clicked) element by class name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't it a bad idea to handle on rightClick in the timeage of mobile devices? they only know the click event, no right click or mouseover. perhaps you better can count the seconds until the touch leaves the image and set it as marked after more than 2 seconds or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.uploadedImage').on('click', function(e){
  // check if it was a rightclick with this if
  if ((e.which && e.which == 3) || (e.button && e.button == 2)) {
    clickedImage.push($(this).attr('_id'));
    console.log(clickedImage);
  }
});
```

if you use a class as selector it works with every element that has assigned this class, and the click listener has not to be in the selector ;)

Comment: Thanks! I updated my code with your suggested code, but JavaScript seems to by-pass it. Perhaps you forgot that your code is to be wrapped in the 'contextmenu .uploadedImage': function(){  }? Looking forward to your response...